# Login to another page to set Cookie

Tags: java, servlets, cookies

I have a form on my local site that when I click on "Login", I want the following things to happen:

- Go to another page
- Fill out form and click submit on that page
- Go back to my local page and continue logging in locally

The reason I need it to go to the other page and login is so it sets a cookie that I need locally. If possible, it would be great if it is done in the background where I can't tell it went to the other page and logged in (hidden iframe?).

It would also be great if I don't have to use some testing framework like Selenium or HTMLUnit as the code will be in a servlet java file.

I was thinking of using `java.net.HttpURLConnection`, but not quite sure what to use from there to make this work.

Any information would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: what you mean is understandable, but I think by using cookies you can manage session till the domain is alive, but not recommend you to store user credentials inside it, see this simple example on your need: http://www.studytonight.com/servlet/storing-session-using-cookies.php

Comment: "Login to another page" and "to set Cookie" doesn't make much sense in the same sentence. You should clarify a little bit how you want to achieve your goal with cookies. In a normal scenario (using normal browsers) you cannot share cookies between different domains, which is your case. Your question is quite cryptic and far from being straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I am not trying to store user info in the cookie. I have an external service I call locally and that service looks for a cookie which is set if I log on to my other site. Then that external service sends back a response depending on the cookie value. Sorry I don't know exactly how to word it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any reason why this should not work with HtmlUnit. HtmlUnit is a headless browser; means you can use it from your servlet without problems and without any ui related dependencies. Your program has complete access to the cookie store, you are able to read the available cokies from the 'external' login and you can do what ever you like with them.